# conversion from dp to pixel wrong

Tags: android, android-layout

For some odd reason, I could n't get the proper output from the below function, I know I did some silly mistake but not sure though,

```
public static int convertDpToPixel(int dp, Context context){
       float px = TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP,dp,context.getResources().getDisplayMetrics());
        return Math.round(px);
    }
```

and i am calling the function as -       `gen_function.convertDpToPixel(R.dimen.button_left_right_margin,this);`

The output is a huge number which is not expected, any help much appreciated.

Comment: Use  `public static float convertDpToPixel(float dp, Context context) {
        Resources resources = context.getResources();
        DisplayMetrics metrics = resources.getDisplayMetrics();
        float px = dp * ((float) metrics.densityDpi / DisplayMetrics.DENSITY_DEFAULT);
        return px;
    }`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use this

```
int pixels = getResources().getDimensionPixelSize(R.dimen.button_left_right_margin);
```

Answer (score 3):

Hope it will help you :-

```
public static int convertDpIntoPx(Context mContext, float yourdpmeasure) {
    if (mContext == null) {
        return 0;
    }
    Resources r = mContext.getResources();
    int px = (int) TypedValue
            .applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, yourdpmeasure, r.getDisplayMetrics());
    return px;
}
```

[For more detail](https://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html#dips-pels)

Answer (score 2):

Hope this will help you.

```
public static int dpToPx(int dp) {

DisplayMetrics displayMetrics = BaseApplication.appContext.getResources().getDisplayMetrics();
 int px = Math.round(dp * (displayMetrics.xdpi / DisplayMetrics.DENSITY_DEFAULT));

return px;

 }
```